# How to merge two finite state automata?

Tags: algorithm, finite-automata, state-machine, deterministic

Say I have two deterministic finite state automata represented by the following transition diagrams:

**FSA for keyword IF:** IF

```
  ___        ___         _
 /   \  I   /   \  F   // \\
>| 0 |----->| 1 |----->||2||
 \___/      \___/      \\_//
```

**FSA for an ID:** [A-Z][A-Z0-9]*

```
            ------------
  ___       | _    LET |
 /   \ LET  // \\<------
>| 0 |----->||1||
 \___/      \\_//<------
            |      NUM |
            ------------
```

What algorithm may I use to combine them into a single deterministic finite state automata with three final states, represented by the following transition diagram:

```
            -----------------------
            | LETTER BUT F OR NUM |   --------
  ___       | _          _   LET  v _ |  LET |
 /   \  I   // \\  F   // \\----->// \\<------
>| 0 |----->||1||----->||2||      ||3||<--------
 \___/      \\_//      \\_//----->\\_//<------ |
   |                         NUM  |      NUM | |
   | ANY LETTER OTHER THAN I      ------------ |
   ---------------------------------------------

1: ID
2: IF (IT'S ALSO AN ID, BUT THE KEYWORD IF HAS A HIGHER PRECEDENCE)
3: ID
```

Comment: Where does the 'NUM' transition between state 2 and 3 come from in the combined machine? Otherwise, It looks like you want to concatenate the machines and add a failure transition from state zero.

Comment: Forgot to add those in a hurry.

Comment: Did you manually draw these ascii arts or you used a tool? Very neat either way.

Comment: @Loax I drew them manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The textbooks usually gives the automaton `C` such that `L(C) = L(A) U L(B)` by applying [de-morgan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) on it, L(C) = (L(A)<sup>C</sup> [intersection] L(B)<sup>C</sup>)<sup>C</sup>.

The intersection is done by building the Cartesian product automaton, and the negation is simply switching the accepting states.

Building the union automaton can also be done directly: Build the Cartesian product automaton, and a final state is a state `(a,b)` such that `a` is a final state in the automaton of `A` OR `b` is a final state in the automaton of `B`

An alternative is building a [Non-Deterministic Final Automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton) (NFA) by simply creating a new state, and add an epsilon path for both start(A) and start(B), and use the standard algorithm for eliminating non-determinism from an automaton.

The problem - this automaton will not be minimal (far from it probably). You can try and use [this algorithm](http://www.cs.uky.edu/~lewis/essays/compilers/min-fa.html) on the resulting automaton in order to minimze it.

Comment: Creating a non-deterministic finite state automaton and converting it into a deterministic finite state automaton is a simple solution. Thank you. I'll also learn about De Morgan's Laws too. =)