# Fastest way to check over 1500 regex pattern match on the same string

Tags: c#, regex

I have over 1500 given regular expression patterns, that need to be run on the same 100 - 200 kb text files and return list of success patterns. Files come from outside, so I can't do any assumption about that file.

The question is, can I somehow make processing faster than running all this regexes to the same text?

Logically the input file is the same, and later regexes can use some information that already have been processed. If we take that each regex is finite automate, than running 1500 finite automates to the same text, is definitely slower than runinng one joined automate. So the question is, can I somehow create that joined regex?

Comment: How are you planning on combining more than 1500 regex ?

Comment: Yes, you can create a joined regex. Given regex A and regex B, the joined regex is `(A) | (B)`. I've done this with a dozen or so, but never tried it with 1,500. It'll be a big string, and I have no idea how well the .NET regex engine will handle it. Would be interesting to try.

Comment: @JimMischel, I thought about that approach but, 1. I think for 1500 regexes, the pattern will be very big and 2. If I put or, the same part of text can match only one side of or operation(I am not sure if this is possible in my case or not yet)

Comment: @Sniffer, that is the question :) do you think it is impossible?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt, if the question is, do we think it is possible then its not a suitable question for SO. Its obviously subjective until someone trys it out and depends on multiple factors outside the scope of the question.

Comment: If you want it to match multiple regexes (that is, you want to know if it matches none, A, B, or A *and* B), then you have no choice but to run the regexes individually. Unless you want to build your own regex version of the Aho-Corasick algorithm. Have you considered using an external tool like `fgrep`?

Comment: Do the regexes change or are they fixed?

Comment: @jodrell, Application read regexes from file, and there are fixed later on... I am not asking if it is possible or not, I am asking how to do that, but the answer could be it is not possible... does that make sense?

Comment: @JimMischel, free third party libs can be used... I will take a look fgrep and see if it can help

Comment: @henginy gave a great answer, and here is implementation http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/677580/Combined-Regular-Expression-Search?msg=4702111#xx4702111xx . it doesn't support all patterns yet, but I think the idea is exactly what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's possible in theory but seems like a non-trivial task. A possible approach could be:

1. Convert all regexes to finite state machines.
2. Combine these into a single fsm.
3. Optimize the generated states.

Optimization would be a key step since the inputs are lengthy (100-200kb). Memory could be a concern and performance could go for worse otherwise. I don't know if a library exists for this purpose but here's a [theoretical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201643/how-to-merge-two-finite-state-automata).

Comment: You've just described what fgrep does.

Comment: @Jim Thank you for mentioning Aho-Corasick algorithm.

Comment: This guy implement that algorithm by parsing regular expression patterns into automates and joining them. it look nice, but however I am afraid it doesn't support everything I may need... However a good idea for library... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/677580/Combined-Regular-Expression-Search

Answer (score 4):

This is a perfect opportunity to take advantage of threading.  Read in your to be processed file into a string, then spin up a series of consumer threads.  Have your main thread put each regular expression into a queue, then have the consumers break off the next piece of the queue, compile the regex, and run it on the string.  The shared memory means you can have several expressions running on the same string, and even on a weak computer (2 cores, not hyperthreaded) you'll notice a significant speed boost if you keep your consumer pool to a reasonable size.  On a really big server - say 32 cores with hyperthreading?  You can have a nice fat pool and blast through those regular expressions in no time.

Comment: Right, but I am processing millions of files, and the processing of each file is less than a second... so I already use a lot of thread resources... but this was my second thought to use different tasks, because regexes are independent

Comment: Well, if you've got the processing of each file down to less than a second, I think you're optimizing the wrong part of the program.  You should find a way to increase the number of files you can process simultaneously.  Perhaps a multi-machine distribution scheme?  One machine acts as a "master" and outsources the processing of the files to your drones, collecting and managing only the results.  You could have these machines share some physical memory (to read in regexes and files), or you could have the master communicate this information.  I think a shared mount is likely the best solution.

Comment: My main question is not about that, I want to optimize search algorithm and not overall process. Aho-Corasick algorithm that henginy mentioned solve this problem with O(l + m) where m is match count and l is text length, but my solution is O(r*l) where r is regulalr expressions count.. first one is about 1500 times faster...

Comment: Actually it was JimMischel who first mentioned Aho-Corasick algorithm on this page. Just wanted to give the credit.